# Method does not return what it should when called

Tags: ios, objective-c, methods, return

I have a piece of code that returns an object of type `Card` like so:

```
-(Card*) drawRandomCard {
    if ([self.cards count]) {
        unsigned index = arc4random() % self.cards.count;
        Card *randomCard = self.cards[index];
        [self.cards removeObjectAtIndex:index];
        NSLog(@"%@", randomCard.description);   **//returns a description and not null**
        return randomCard;
    } else {
        NSLog(@"nil");
        return nil;
    }
}
```

This actually works fine when I use it in other functions, but there is a problem with this one below:

```
- (IBAction)addCards:(UIButton *)sender {
    int numberOfCardsToAdd = EXTRA_CARDS_NUMBER;

    if ([[self.collectionView visibleCells] count] == 0) {
        numberOfCardsToAdd = self.startingCardCount;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfCardsToAdd; i++) {
        if (!self.game.deck.isEmpty){
            Card *cardToAdd = [self.game.deck drawRandomCard];   
            NSLog(@"%@", cardToAdd.description); **// gives (null)**
                if (cardToAdd) {  **// this does not get called**
                    // do stuff with cardToAdd
               }
            }
        }
        [self.collectionView reloadData];
}
```

So for some reason it seems my `drawRandomCard`, when called with the method above, does not work. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks very much!

Edit: my method for initializing the game object that has the `deck` property:

```
- (id) initWithNumberOfCards: (int) numberOfCards withDeck: (SetsPlayingDeck *) deck {
    self = [self init];
    self.score = 0;
    _deck = deck;
    _cards = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:numberOfCards];
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfCards; i++) {
        [_cards addObject: [_deck drawRandomCard]];
    }
    return self;

}
```

This method is called right at the start of the program.

Edit #2:

Here is the code that initializes the game object, along with a deck object that is its property:

```
- (SetsGame *) game {
    if (!_game) {
        SetsPlayingDeck *deck = [[SetsPlayingDeck alloc] init];
        _game = [[SetsGame alloc] initWithCardCount:self.startingCardCount usingDeck:deck];
    }

    NSLog(@"%@", _game.deck.description);  **// this returns null!!**
    return _game;
}
```

Comment: Did you check that `self.game` and `self.game.deck` are both not `nil`? Did you set a breakpoint in the debugger and single-stepped into the method to find the problem?

Comment: I have already tried the debugger, but I just checked as you said and `self.game` is not `nil` but `self.game.deck` is. I don't understand why, though, since `deck` is a strong `@property` of `self.game`, and I set it up when I initialized the `game` object.

Comment: Are you correctly initializing the 'deck' property? Are you sure it is already initialized by the time you try to access it? I'm afraid without seeing more code it's going to be very difficult to spot the problem.

Comment: @LuisCien
I have edited my question with the code where I initialized `deck`

Comment: If `[[self game] deck]` is `nil` then that is your problem.  The problem is not with the random card function.  Do you have `self.game.deck = initWithNumberOfCards…` anywhere?  Are you sure it's called before this button is pressed?

Comment: @AaronBrager Yes, I did initialize it before the button is pressed... I've put the code in the 2nd edit above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see, the issue should lie with the method `initWithCardCount:usingDeck:`, where you probably forgot to assign the `deck` argument to the `deck` property (or for some reason the assignment is not executed):

```
    _game = [[SetsGame alloc] initWithCardCount:self.startingCardCount usingDeck:deck];
```

So, please review this or post that method definition.

Comment: Thank you for this! I checked and turned out my the methods in my model and my controller don't match: `- (id) initWithNumberOfCards: (int) numberOfCards withDeck: (SetsPlayingDeck *) deck` in the game model should have been `- (id) initWithCardCount: (int) numberOfCards withDeck: (SetsPlayingDeck *) deck` instead!

Answer (score -1):

Maybe the problem is that you're running out of cards. Inside your init method you have the following line inside a for-loop:

```
[_cards addObject: [_deck drawRandomCard]];
```

And inside your `drawRandomCard` method you have the following line:

```
[self.cards removeObjectAtIndex:index];
```

I'm assuming that `_cards`(1st line) and `self.cards`(2nd line) are different objects.

Probably, by the time you call `Card *cardToAdd = [self.game.deck drawRandomCard];` inside your `addCards:` method you don't have any cards left.

Try to set a breakpoint and step in the for-loop and let me know,

Hope this helps!

Comment: Unfortunately that is not the problem. I have set a breakpoint and an `NSLog` up but the cards that `drawRandomCard` was supposed to draw from was no where near running out.